# Method to detach a kickstand bracket stuck to bike frame?

Tags: kickstand

I installed a third-party kickstand on my bike when I first got it. It's seen lots of riding, rain and now a winter.

I upgraded to a dual-leg kickstand for better balance when loaded down with utility runs. Bit after removing the kickstand bolt, I discovered the kickstand bracket was stuck to the frame.

After a could of gentle whacks I decided to educate myself a bit more before I broke something I'd regret. Any suggestions on how to break the pieces apart as cleanly as possible so I can install the new kickstand?

I only have a basic set of tools and no real workshop (but I do have a work stand). If it's anything advanced I'll head to the LBS and see what they suggest. Thought I'd try my hand at it first.

[image: Kickstand detail photo]

Comment: Could you give some pictures of how the kickstand is attached on your bike?

Comment: some less gentle whacks would be my choice.

Comment: Spray on some WD-40 or similar and let soak for a night.

Comment: Winter riding?  If you're in a salted region, then corrosion is a suspect.  Penetrating oil for a day, then use leverage like an old chisel .  A photo would help give us more to go on.

Comment: If you're sure you've removed all the bolts, and the frame is steel, just whack it harder.  But study it carefully to see if some portion of the bracket has become wedged between the chain stays, or some such.

Comment: Photo added. My concern was corrosion and perhaps breaking off part of the kickstand and having it stuck to the frame, hence the gentle whacks approach to begin with. I'd rather have the old kickstand than none at all!

Comment: @GeorgeC - A shot between the chainstays would be good too.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have one, but a small propane torch is what I use when I can't remove metal parts and oil isn't doing the job. Just be mindful of which parts are getting the heat. You don't want to ruin your paint job.

Comment: In the picture, it looks to me like there is a metal bracket of sorts welded/brazed to the seat stays, and the kickstand sort of wedges itself into the bracket.  I'm guessing the kickstand anchor is simply wedged in there and needs to be pried/knocked out.

Comment: I have applied the penetrating oil and will be attempting another removal this weekend.

Comment: Success! It turns out the bolt had become wedged to both the frame and the kickstand bracket. A bit of cranking with a hex wrench did the trick. I'm sure the penetrating oil helped. Not sure how to mark this one.

Answer (score 4):

Why bother being nice to it?  Noone likes those kickstands, they are soon removed from most bikes.  And many cyclists have one or more in their spares boxes!

Please have a good look for a second bolt too - I've never seen one with two bolts, but yours could possibly have a second.

You can also try

- blast the whole joint with penetrating oil like CRC or rustblaster or RP7 or similar.
- re-threadding the bolt part-way in and then tap on that
- shove a scraper or a chisel between stand and frame and lever it
- just belt the side of the kickstand with a hammer, use a rubber mallett or a block of wood if you want to avoid damaging the paint.
- use the leg as leverage - grab then end and wiggle it both in the closed and open position.

Do let us know how you get on.

Comment: I don't understand the dislike for kickstands. I added this one myself after tiring of finding places to lean the bike to take photos, breaks, eat, etc. At any rate, my main concern is breaking the kickstand and still having a chunk stuck to the bike. And of course, damaging the bike frame.

Comment: @GeorgeC the two-legged stands are great if you need them.  The cheap single ones with a pointy foot are not so good, and your bike is much more likely to fall over because of them.  Hence the dislike.

Comment: never had an issue with the current single-leg kickstand, at least without a cargo load (hence the upgrade). In fact, my bike is 100% sure to fall over without the kickstand :)

Answer (score 0):

While I can appreciate not "being nice" you might both being nice to avoid damaging other parts.  I wondered if a new metal cutting place might work there?  The space is tight, so you might need to saw it by hand, but in doing so you would not damage other components.

Comment: Using a hand saw is more likely to damage things in my experience.  A smaller 4" / 100mm grinder with a thin INOX cutoff wheel works well, or if thats too awkward to get in, a 1" cutoff wheel on a dremel tool is good.  They don't last long is the only problem.